# Selenium capture user input

Tags: selenium

I'm looking for a easy to configure design for a small task, a capture the field and user input on a third party website, with the authorization of the user. 
I want something that can withstand changes to the third party. Or a design in which these changes are easy to incorporate changes.

Any ideas on what I should be looking at, examples would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to make a sort of a key logger?

Comment: Not sure what you mean actually. just capturing the user input from a third party site..